# sending message out of a sandbox to a custom application

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, sandbox

I got an application which uses flash for it's interfaces, and I want to extract information from this application, and parse/use it in my own application (which processes the data, stores the essentials in a mysqldb and so on). 
The `.swf` files are written in AS2 and can be modded quite easily.

So my goal is to send information (really just information. Being able to send numbers (of a at least decent size) would enable me to implement my own protocol of encoding and partitioning) by any means, I am certainly not picky about the means.

Here is my current approach (not my own idea, credits to koreanrandom.org. I merely use their source to learn):

- use DokanLib to mount a virtual filesystem (and implement the `getFileInformation`-handler)
- use `LoadVars` inside the AS2-Environment with parameters like `"../.logger/@encoded_information"`
- since `getFileInformation` gets the accessed filename as a parameter, I can decode it, put several ones back together (if they had to be splitted, windows does not seem to like filenames with several hundred characters length) and use the decoded data

However, my application causes bluescreens quite often (dont ask why. i got no clue, the bluescreen messages are always different) and the devs at koreanrandom.org dont like being asked too many questions, so i came to ask here for other means to pass information from a sandboxed flash-environment to a prepared listener.

I started thinking about weird stuff (ok, abusing a virtual filesystem & filenames as a means of transport for information might be weird too - but it is still a great idea imo) like provoking certain windows-functions to be called and work with global hooks, but i didnt grasp a serious plan yet.

The "usual" methods like accessing webservers via methods like this dont appear to work:

```
var target_mc = createEmptyMovieClip("target_mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
loadVariables("http://127.0.0.1/Tools/indata.php", "target_mc", "GET");
```

(`indata.php` would have created a file, if it was accessed, but it didnt.)

`XMLSocket` doesnt work either, i tried the following code sample (using `netcat -l` on port 12345):

```
Logger.add("begin");
var theSocket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();
theSocket.onConnect = function(myStatus) {
    if (myStatus) {
        Logger.add("XMLSocket sucessfully connected")
    }   else {
        Logger.add("XMLSocket NO CONNECTION");
    }
};
theSocket.connect("127.0.0.1", 12345);
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var mySend = myXML.createElement("thenode");
mySend.attributes.myData = "someData";
myXML.appendChild(mySend);
theSocket.send(myXML);
Logger.add("socket sent");
```

doesnt work at all either, the output of the logger was just `begin` and `socket sent`

Annotation: the logger was created by the guys from koreanrandom.org and relies on their dokan implementation, which never caused a bluescreen for me. cant spot my mistake in my implementation though, so i started to look for other means of solving my problem.

**EDIT**: what the hell is wrong with your "quality messages system"? appearently it didnt like me using the tags "escaping" and/or "information".

Comment: You should try to avoid using so much (long) parentheses inside your sentences, it breaks the flow and makes it hard to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hmm, hard to say, try sendAndLoad instead of loadVariables

example:

```
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
send_lv.variable1=value1;
send_lv.variable2=value2;

    f=this;//zachytka

result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
  if (success) {
trace("ok");
  } else {
    trace("error");
  }

};

send_lv.sendAndLoad("http://127.0.0.1/Tools/indata.php", result_lv, "GET"); //you may also use POST
```

this should work. the reason it's not working may also be flash security settings. try either moving the stuff to a real server or open up the [flash settings manager](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html) (there's an [alternative online version](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html) too) and add the 127.0.0.1 to trusted domains and/or testing file location to the trusted locations (i use C:*)